# How to use fontFeatureSettings and spanned string in the same Android TextView?

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to display some text in compose that contains some html tags that should be applied.

e.g. `This is a string with <b>bold</b> and <i>italics</i><br><br>also line breaks`

Since compose doesn't support html strings I'm create an android view to use a `TextView` with `Html.fromHtml(...)` to get the formatting from the html tags. This works until I try and change the font feature settings by uncommenting the line `fontFeatureSettings = "ss01"`

How can I change the font feature settings and keep the html formatting (which uses `Spanned`)? Is it an android bug that my code doesn't work or am I doing something wrong?

```kotlin
@Composable
fun HtmlText(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    htmlText: String,
) {
    var reviewTypeface by remember { mutableStateOf<Typeface?>(null) }

    AndroidView(
        modifier = modifier.semantics { text = AnnotatedString(htmlText) },
        factory = {
            getFont(it, R.font.public_sans_regular) { typeface ->
                reviewTypeface = typeface
            }
            
            TextView(it).apply {
                text = Html.fromHtml(htmlText, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_COMPACT)
//                fontFeatureSettings = "ss01"
            }
        }
    ) {
        reviewTypeface?.let { typeface ->
            it.setTypeface(typeface, Typeface.NORMAL)
            reviewTypeface = null
        }
    }
}

fun getFont(context: Context, @FontRes id: Int, onReceived: (Typeface) -> Unit) {
    ResourcesCompat.getCachedFont(context, id)?.let { onReceived(it) }
    ResourcesCompat.getFont(
        context,
        R.font.public_sans_regular,
        object : ResourcesCompat.FontCallback() {
            override fun onFontRetrieved(typeface: Typeface) {
                onReceived(typeface)
            }

            override fun onFontRetrievalFailed(reason: Int) {}
        },
        null
    )
}
```

[image: Screenshot comparison of without the fontFeatureSettings and with teh fontFeatureSettings set]